# How Does Groovy Support Adding Configuration in Gradle Configuration Script Block

Tags: gradle, groovy

In the [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ConfigurationContainer.html) when you use a `configurations` block in your build.gradle file the closure that is passed delegates to a `ConfigurationContainer` object. A truncated form of the example usage is given below:

```
configurations {
  //adding a configuration:
  myConfiguration
}
```

I am used to the calls inside the closure being method calls on the delegated to object, but here `myConfiguration` is just a single word and I know that in Groovy a method with no parameters must have parentheses so this can't be a method call. Somehow by putting this single word in which looks to me like it should be invalid Groovy a new configuration of `myConfiguration` is added to the delegated to `ConfigurationContainer`.

How is this working?

Answer (score 0):

**Project.configurations(Closure)** calls **ConfigurationContainer.configure(Closure)**, which creates and adds named items to container, as they declared in closure. Because **ConfigurationContainer** extends **NamedDomainObjectContainer**, every item added to It should have name. In provided code sample only name is declared, so myConfiguration item is created and added, with default field values. In case one needs to configure item (change its properties), then configuration would look as follows:

```
   configurations {
     myConfiguration {
        transitive = false
     }
   }
```

More info/insights https://gist.github.com/tlberglund/3132622.